# Excel: Extract full months between date ranges

Tags: excel, date

Users are entering date ranges into an Excel spreadsheet. These date ranges span multiple months. What I'd like is for a field to display how many full months are represented in the date range.

For example:

User enters `8/25/2014` and `12/19/2014`

Calculated field = `3`

The full months represent September, October, and November. August and December are only partial months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming start date in A2 and end date in B2 use this formula for the number of full months

`=DATEDIF(EOMONTH(A2-1,0)+1,B2+1,"m")`

That will give you 3 for your example - if you change the start date to 8/1/2014 (or the end date to 12/31/2014) you will get 4 (or if you do both you'll get 5)

Comment: Works like a dream. Thank you.